# Theorem or Justification for the function with a given finite integral over an interval with the lowwest maximum value being a constant.

Tags: calculus

In a paper I'm writing, I'm trying to find a formal theorem or other concise way of stating that in the space of continuous functions whose definite integral over the over the interval $\,0 \leq t\leq t_f$ is equal to a given constant, positive value,
$\int_0^{t_f}\,\mathcal{f}(t)=C$ , the function $\mathcal{f}(t)$ with the lowest maximum value is a constant. The principle seems self evident but for my purposes I would like to have a way to show this definitively. Because I'm currently going off of the self evidence of the thing, I could very well be wrong, so I would also like to have a definitive answer before proceeding in the paper but I've been struggling to find any information on this problem, or to demonstrate it myself.

Comment: This is false if you allow discontinuous functions.

Comment: You are correct! Thank you very much. I've edited the question to allow only for continuous functions.